# Dimension of soft buttons bar

Tags: android

Is there a way to determine the dimension (width) of the menu bar of devices without hard menu buttons? (like the archos devices).

I need to know the usable dimension of the screen...

Answer (score 15):

This method is very useful in order to set the layout padding in Android KitKat (4.4). Using this, you can avoid the soft buttons bar overlapping over your layout.

The `getRealMetrics` method is only available with API 17 and +, but I'm only using the following method I wrote for devices on API 19+

```java
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private int getSoftbuttonsbarHeight() {
    // getRealMetrics is only available with API 17 and +
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return 0;
    }

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
    int realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    return realHeight > usableHeight ? realHeight - usableHeight : 0;
}
```

Tested upon Nexus 5 & Nexus 7 2013.

Comment: It seems that wrong results being returned for landscape screen mode

Comment: I haven't had any issue with landscape mode. Is your method called again on rotation change?

Comment: no, I meant that in some cases you need to check difference in width but not height. When soft keys are on the right of landscape-mode rotated screen?

Answer (score 4):

A very late answer but for anyone that encounters this problem. A simple way to get the amount of usable space offsetting any soft keys/navigation bar or even the status bar, is to use getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(Rect) from the Apps DecorView. This will load a Rect object with the dimension of the display that is actually usable.

Since you cannot directly get a reference to the Activiy's DecorView, you need to first get the Activity's window using the accessor method, getWindow(). This will return the window object that holds the Activity and other screen elements. To get the decorView that contains the activity as well as the screen decorations i.e. the status bar, navigation bar/soft button bar, call accessor method getDecorView(). Once your have a reference to the DecorView call getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(Rect) and you will have a loaded Rect object.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Andorid 3.2, the height of system status bar is not included in DisplayMetrics's height, you have to use undocumented APIs (Display.getRawWidth() and Display.getRawHeight()) to get the physical screen width or height.

```
Method mGetRawW = Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth");
Method mGetRawH = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");

int nW = (Integer)mGetRawW.invoke(dp);
int nH = (Integer)mGetRawH.invoke(dp);
```

UPDATED: For API 13-16, you have to use the above code to get real width/height. For API 17+, you can now use the new public API, `Display.getRealSize()`

Comment: What's is dp in (Integer)mGetRawW.invoke(dp); And it will return height with Soft menu included .

Comment: It gives me a NoSuchMethodException Exception.

Comment: What is dp? Also couldn't find both methods (NoSuchMethod Exception)

Answer (score 0):

for me, in android note 10, I need to get navigation bar height by dimen:

```
fun getSoftNavigationBarSize(resources: Resources): Int {
var result = 0
val resourceId: Int = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
if (resourceId > 0) {
    result = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
}
return result
```

}