# How to adjust background image to fit devices with software and hardware buttons?

Tags: android, user-interface, screen-resolution

I'm developing a game, my background has 1920x1080 resolution. 
It looks fine when on a device with hardware buttons (Galaxy 5), but on Nexus 5 (with software buttons) the background is visibly shortened (square looks like a rectangle now), because the softwarte buttons take some of this resolution.

How can I handle this situation? Can I make soft buttons "overlap" my activity and have some gradient instead of black background?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689117/dimension-of-soft-buttons-bar). I think what you need to do is to set your main container's bottom margin to whatever value you get from the virtual buttons' height. Good luck, I did it this way and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

As an option can use notlong qualifiers for layout and resource folders.
e.g. devices with software buttons will use the resources from `layout-notlong` folder if exists.