# Android: Calculate Bottom function / Panel bar's Height

Tags: android

I would like to know how to get the Height of "Panel Bar", which is at the bottom of the phone. (Highlighted with the blue blanket)
Many thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dimension of soft buttons bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689117/dimension-of-soft-buttons-bar)